# Accessing data in var format for D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble understanding why my code won't work.

I am getting an error on `.attr('r', function(d)`

I am assigning a number to `year` and creating a variable called `category` by adding `d.p` and `year`. The name of each data category in my csv file is p1900, p1901, p1902, p1903, etc. And I try to access it in `.attr('r', function(d)` but it doesn't seem to register.

```
  cityPoints.attr('cx', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]})
       .attr('cy', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]})
       .attr('r', function(d) {

       var category = "d.p"+year;
           if (scale(category) != null) {return scale(category) + 'px'}
           else {return '0px'};
           ;})
       .attr('stroke', 'white');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually accessing the `d` object, just working on a string called `d.p1900` instead.

Try doing this:

```
cityPoints.attr('cx', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]})
    .attr('cy', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]})
    .attr('r', function(d) {

        var category = "p" + year;
        if (scale(d[category]) != null) {
            return scale(d[category]) + 'px';
        } else { return '0px' };

    }).attr('stroke', 'white');
```